# Determinig Available IP address

Tags: php, networking, ip

Is there any method to determine the list of available ip addresses within a lan network
using php? That is,

suppose LAN comprises of 100 computers connected. And in due course of time some computers are working on dynamic ip and the others have static ip. How to determine the available IP in the network, so that static IP could be allocated to the computers working on Dynamic IP?

Comment: This sounds like a job for which there might be a ready-made tool on the command line. What OS are you on?

Comment: this is one more issue. Some system uses linux fedora and some windows xp. The lan is connected to internal server which works on unix

Comment: I think the ideal way would be to ask the DHCP server. If it has a function to show all the used IPs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> suppose LAN comprises of 100 computers connected. And in due course of time some computers are working on dynamic ip and the others have static ip. How to determine the available IP in the network, so that static IP could be allocated to the computers working on Dynamic IP?

Ehrm? You could either ask the DHCP server somehow, or you could ping each possible machine in the subnet to see which IP address is used and which isn't. Alas, this isn't fool-proof and truth be told; it seems to me this would be the responsibility of the DHCP server.

The ping is rather easy:

```
<?php
for( $i = 1; $i < 255; $i ++ ) { /* Naturally, this only goes for /24 networks */
    $address = '10.10.10.' . $i;

    $out = shell_exec( 'ping ' . $address );
    var_dump( $out );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no such function in `PHP` but you can get the list of all ip address one by one and store it in a array